# Is there any reason to prefer one phrasing over the other?

Tags: soft-question

The following two sentences in the language of $\mathbb{N}$ are logically equivalent, in the sense that first-order logic alone is enough to get from one to the other.

1. For all $a,b;$ if there exists $k$ such that $ak=b$, then $a\mid b$.
2. For all $a,b$ and all $k$, if $ak=b$, then $a\mid b$.

Many similar examples abound in mathematics. Is there any reason to prefer one phrasing over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first variant seems to occur more naturally and match the ways we think as it compares two predicates $\Phi(a,b) \equiv \exists k(ak=b)$ and $\Psi(a,b)\equiv a|b$. It also has the advantage that we can in fact formulate the equivalence
$$ \forall a\forall b(\exists k(ak=b)\leftrightarrow a|b).$$
On the other hand, the second variant has the advantage that all quantors have been "pulled out". Moreover, there is no existential quantifier so that we may infer
$$ ak=b\to a|b$$
for arbitrary values of $k,a,b$, which can be advantageous for formal deductions.